# Binding to a grid

Tags: c#, silverlight

I Have the following class that I want to bind to a grid but its not woking - any guidence appreciated

Class 1 :

```
public class Assessments

{

public AssessmentHeader AssessmentHeader { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<AssessmentSurveyHeaders> AssessmentSurveys { get; set; }

}

Class 2:

public class AssessmentSurveyHeaders

{

public AssessmentSurvey AssessmentSurvey { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<SurveyLines> AssessmentSurveyLines { get; set; }

 }

Class 3:

public class AssessmentSurvey 

{

public Guid SurveyId{ get; set; }

 public string Description{ get; set; }

}
```

Grid Bindings:

```
                <data:DataGrid x:Name="QuestionGrid" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderGlassEffect}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding _Assessments, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Assessment">
                        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="AssessmentLink" Tag="{Binding AssessmentHeader.AssessmentGuid}" Content="{Binding AssessmentHeader.AssessmentGuid}" Click="AssessmentLink_Click"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SurveyId">
                            <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate >
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <data:DataGrid x:Name="SurveysGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding AssessmentSurveys, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"  Binding="{Binding AssessmentSurveys.AssessmentSurvey.SurveyGuid, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"  Binding="{Binding AssessmentSurveys.AssessmentSurvey.Description, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="True"/>
                                        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </data:DataGrid>               
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </data:DataGrid.Columns>
                </data:DataGrid>
```

Comment: which type of your ObservableCollection in class1? And why class 2 and class 3 have same name **"AssessmentSurveyHeaders"**? It is unclear to make a relationship among all three classes.

Comment: Amended it again - for some reason it was stripping some of my data on here

Comment: @user367338 what is the **_Assessments** at the first line? is it an instance name of the Assessments class? If so, the binding will not work because the class1 itself is not a Collection. ItemsSource has to be binded with a Collection.

Comment: It wont bind the ID and Description within AssessmentSurveys.AssessmentSurvey

Comment: _assessments is an Observable collection of Class 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID and Description are already binded with AssessmentSurveys at ItemsSource.

In other words, you don't need to write **AssessmentSurveys** of each child item.

please try below.

```
                         <data:DataGrid.Columns> 
                                        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"  Binding="{Binding AssessmentSurvey.SurveyGuid, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="True"/> 
                                        <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"  Binding="{Binding AssessmentSurvey.Description, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsReadOnly="True"/> 
                                    </data:DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Ahh i see - thanx for your help and quick response it is much appreciated